# Six friends sit in adjoining seats in a row. A wall, 6 seats, an aisle, 6 more seats, then a wall

Tags: permutations, combinations

"How many ways can they sit if Jane and Mary refuse to sit next to each other and John refuses to sit on an end?"

I've figured out how many ways all 6 can sit together. 6! * 2(sides of the theater)=1440
I the figured out how many ways the two friends could sit together and then subtract that amount. 5!*2!*2(sides of the theater) and end up with 1440-480=960 ways to sit.

However, the last part of the question is confusing me.  "John refuses to sit on an end".

Please help.

Comment: "*Six friends sit in adjoining seats in a row*"... It isn't perfectly clear to me what "adjoining" means in this context.  By your count of $6!\cdot 2$ you seem to be interpreting it as that implies that all friends are on the same side of the aisle, but is that really what is intended?  If the seats were labeled $a,b,c,d,e,\dots,l$ we aren't counting the possibility that they sit in the seats $d,e,f,g,h,i$?  "Sitting on an end" is in reference to either sitting by the wall or sitting in an aisle seat?

Comment: You need to consider two separate cases: One, when both the sitting on the same side of aisle and other when both are sitting on opposite side of aisle. Hint use distribution then arrangement

Comment: Hmm that's a good point.  I just reached to specify the specifics of that.  I guess that changes everything doesn't it.  I'll report back ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your interpretation. Seats that have an aisle between them are not adjoining. To solve: Use Inclusion/Exclusion.

Total number of orders, as you identified, is $12\times 5!$ (there are $12$ seats for the first person, but once they are selected, everyone else has to sit on the same side of the aisle, so there are $5!$ ways to place everyone else)

Number of ways for John to be at an end: $4\times 5!$ (there are $4$ end seats, but once John is placed, everyone else has to sit on the same side of the aisle, and there are $5!$ ways to seat them).

Number of ways for Jane and Mary to be next to each other: $10\times 2!\times 4!$ (There are $10$ pairs of adjacent seats that are not separated by an aisle. Once you choose a pair, choose an order for Jane and Mary, then place everyone else on the same side of the aisle in $4!$ ways)

Number of ways for Jane and Mary to be next to each other while John is at an end: $4\times 4\times 2!\times 3!$ (There are $4$ end seats to place John. Regardless of which spot you put John, there are $4$ adjacent pairs of sets on the same side of the aisle for Mary and Jane. Choose an order for them, and then there are $3!$ ways to seat the remaining three people).

Total ways with Jane and Mary separated and John not at the end:

$$12\times 5! - 4\times 5! - 10\times 2!\times 4! + 4\times 4\times 2!\times 3! = 672$$

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you sooooo much!!!!

Comment: @RyBoneCoder I added explanations for my calculations.